How to show a non array key/value object in a kibana graph?
I'm trying to create a dashboard in Kibana to graphicaly show "the most used query parameters", but I cannot get this working.
I have an index that contains request logs data, and in each document there is a field "query" with data for each query string used, as follows (other fields ommited):
{
    "_index": "idxname",
    "_source": {
      "query": {
        "a": "ALL",
        "b": "1",
        "l": "en"
      }
    }
},
{
    "_index": "idxname",
    "_source": {
      "query": {
        "a": "ALL",
        "c": "45",
        "l": "en"
      }
    }
}

Notice that there are values that exists in one document but not in other. Here is the mapping of this field for reference:
"query": {
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "c": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

What I'm doing? I aggregate those fields to count in how many documents they are present, so I can identify "the most used parameters". I do this using aggregations, as the exemple below (I can use value_count or filter/exists to reach this):
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "A": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "query.a.keyword"
      }
    },
    "B": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "query.b.keyword"
      }
    },
    "C": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "query.c.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

And the results are like this:
"aggregations": {
    "A": {
      "value": 71537
    },
    "B": {
      "value": 77386
    },
    "C": {
      "value": 71827
    }
  }

Here is my problem: as the results are like a key/pair value object, I don't realize how to plot as a graph lines or bars in the kibana. I'm using vega as well (since my elasticsearch version is 8.12.2, I use "custom visualization", that uses vega).
My question is, how can I plot those results as graph, since the x/y axis are based in arrays not in key/value object? Is there a way to do this using the transform expression in vega, or maybe another way to do the query, in a way that the aggregate values appears as an array?
What I expect is something like this in kibana:

This is my experimental code in kibana:
{

  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json
  title: Test

  // Define the data source
  data: {
    url: {

      // Apply dashboard context filters when set
      %context%: true
      // Filter the time picker (upper right corner) with this field
      %timefield%: @timestamp

      // Which index to search
      index: indexname
      // Aggregate data by the time field into time buckets, counting the number of documents in each bucket.
      body: {
        aggs: {
          "count_fields": {
            "global": {},
            "aggs": {
              "A": {
                "value_count": {
                  "field": "query.a.keyword"
                }
              },
              "B": {
                "value_count": {
                  "field": "query.b.keyword"
                }
              },
              "C": {
                "value_count": {
                  "field": "query.c.keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        // Speed up the response by only including aggregation results
        size: 0
      }
    }
  
    format: {property: "aggregations.count_fields"}
  
  }

  "mark": "text",
  "style": "text",
  "encoding": {"text": {"field": "A.value", "type": "string"}},
}

As expected, since the source data is not an array, I can only show the value of any of my keys, in the code above, "A.value"
